# C - Error al enlazar valores con una LDE e impresión de tokens

Tags: c, lista, tokens

Estoy trabajando con un fichero csv (lo adjunto aquí: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1unMDSfTHtanoei5rURXxlNZ-LFsQIVhy/view?usp=sharing) del cual tengo que, entre otras cosas, hacer un código en C que almacene los valores de cada fila y de cada columna para luego poder hacer algunas operaciones con ellos. Estoy en la fase de almacenar los valores y estoy usando una pila implementada con una LDE (lista doblemente enlazada) para ello. De cada uno de esos “nodos” que estoy creando necesita almacenar su fila correspondiente, su columna correspondiente y su valor. A la hora de implementar el método de visualizar me da un error a la hora de asignar el valor al nodo actual. También tengo un problema inesperado en el main que es que solo se me van imprimiendo los token (los valores) de la primera fila, no de todas las filas como ocurriría si quitase todas las líneas referentes a la asignación de nodos.

Aquí dejo mi código. He indicado con comentarios las partes de los errores.

```
//VERSIÓN 2.0 - 21 marzo de 2020 18:25
//Versión de Ubuntu: 14.04 LTS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 256

typedef struct Datos{
    int filaCorrespondiente;
    int columnaCorrespondiente;
    char valorCorrespondiente;
} datos;

typedef struct Nodo{
    struct Nodo *anterior;
    datos d;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} nodo;

nodo *crearNodo(datos d);
nodo * insertar(nodo *cima, nodo *nuevoNodo);
void listar(nodo *cima);
void visualizar(nodo *actual);


int main(){

    nodo *cima = NULL;
    datos d;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    f = fopen("BreastTissueTrain.csv", "r");
    int filaActual=1, columnaActual=1;

    char linea[MAX];

    printf("\n");

    if(f){
            fgets(linea, MAX, f);
            while(!feof(f)){
            char *token = strtok(linea, ",");
            while(token!=NULL){
                printf("%s ", token); //FALLO. Me termina imprimiendo solamente la primera línea

                fscanf(f, "%s", &(d.valorCorrespondiente));
                (d.filaCorrespondiente) = filaActual;
                (d.columnaCorrespondiente) = columnaActual;
                cima = insertar(cima, crearNodo(d));
                columnaActual++;

                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
            fgets(linea, MAX, f);
            filaActual++;
        }
        }
    printf("\n\n\n");
        fclose(f);

    printf("Visualización de los valores de los nodos en el fichero csv...\n");
    listar(cima);

    return 0;
}

nodo *crearNodo(datos d){
    nodo *nuevoNodo=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    nuevoNodo->d.filaCorrespondiente = d.filaCorrespondiente;
    nuevoNodo->d.columnaCorrespondiente = d.columnaCorrespondiente;
    nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente = d.valorCorrespondiente;
    nuevoNodo->anterior = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->siguiente = NULL;
    return nuevoNodo;
}

nodo *insertar(nodo *cima, nodo *nuevoNodo){
    if(cima==NULL){
        cima=nuevoNodo;
    }else{
        nuevoNodo->siguiente=cima;
        cima->anterior=nuevoNodo;
        cima=nuevoNodo;
    }
    return cima;
}

void listar(nodo *cima){ //Al listarlo empieza del final al principio al ser pila
    nodo *actual;
    if(cima==NULL){
        printf("ERROR. La pila esta vacia");
    }else{
        for(actual=cima; actual!=NULL; actual=actual->siguiente){
            visualizar(actual);
        }
    }
}

void visualizar(nodo *actual){
    //printf("\n\nValor: %s", actual->d.valorCorrespondiente); //FALLO. Si "descomento" esta línea me da error a la hora de asignar el valor
    printf("\nFila: %d", actual->d.filaCorrespondiente);
    printf("\nColumna: %d\n\n", actual->d.columnaCorrespondiente);
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué error da el método `visualizar`? ¿Fallo de segmentación?

Comment: @MrDave1999 Me da una warning a la hora de la asignación del formato:
`
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("\n\nValor: %s", actual->d.valorCorrespondiente); //FALLO. Me da error a la hora de asignar el valor
`
Y luego sí me sale el segmentation fault a la hora de ejecutarlo

Comment: El error se debe porque el tipo de `valorCorrespondiente` es `char` y debería ser `char*`. Esto quiere decir que la variable como es de tipo `char`, almacena un caracter y es ilegal usar el especificador `%s` en el `printf`, debido a que, esto imprime una cadena de caracteres, no un solo caracter. Ahora, la pregunta es, ¿necesitas imprimir un caracter o una cadena? Porque si es un solo caracter, deberías usar `%c`.

Comment: Tal como se ve en el fichero que adjunto en la pregunta, son valores de más de 1 caracter. Algunos son float, otros son int y otros son String. Me ha dicho mi profesora de universidad sobre esto que puedo hacerlo directamente considerando todos los valores como String (y por tanto, de más de un caracter)

Comment: Si es así. La variable `valorCorrespondiente` debería ser declarado como `char valorCorrespondiente[50]` (un arreglo de caracteres). Ahí necesitarías buscar el tamaño apropiado para el arreglo, así evitas el desbordamiento de búfer. Con esto, la falla de segmentación debería de solucionarse.

Comment: No me ha funcionado. Al hacerlo pasa de warning a error por la conversión de tipos de la línea `nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente = d.valorCorrespondiente;`

Comment: Ahí necesitas copiar los caracteres de un arreglo en el otro y esto se lo hace a través de la función `strcpy`. Ej: `strcpy(nuevoNodo->d.valorCorrespondiente, d.valorCorrespondiente);`

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho y he reservado memoria y ya me funciona. He tardado casi dos días en darme cuenta porque soy bastante novato con los malloc jeje. Gracias

Comment: De nada! Si tienes alguna duda sobre el tema de memoria dinámica, no olvides de preguntar.